# UIImagePickerController delegate to different ViewController after taking Picker

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a simple button within my Main-View Controller. After calling imagePickerController and taking a picture, I want to redirect the user to the next view controller to continue processing the image. Somehow it always returns to my main window.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you have to push your view Like

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ...

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        ...
        YourImgViewController *imgProcessing = [[YourImgViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourImgViewController" bundle:nil];
        imgProcessing.selectedImageView.image = image;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:imgProcessing animated:YES];
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

very simple!

you can find more hint on this link http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/how-to-make-an-app-2/tutorial-on-image-picker-controller-in-iphone/

Comment: Many thanks, it did work. The only drawback right now is, the View I'm loading is compeletely black, it should display another UIView (not the image), even though my NSLogs seem ok.

Comment: can you explain it with more details?
Or with Code

Comment: The View I'm loading contains a MKMapView, which should show the current location, which it perfectly does if I navigate to the view via a Button and a push action. If I load it through the code you provided me, it shows just a blank view with nothing. Within the viewDidLoad of the View I just put a NSLog to see when its loaded, this is getting displayed.